# SQL Query - need to be able to return nothing if query is not successful

Tags: java, jdbc

I am working to populate a User Details page, and at the moment, I am logged in as null user and it keeps breaking because this query has to return something.
I want to make it so that if it is empty, it will return ""; instead of breaking.

I have a vague idea how to do this but I need help! The query definitely works when a user is logged in because I have tested the code, and it populates when there is a valid user.

I think it should be something like:

```
 @Override
        public UserDetails fetchUserById(int userId) {
            String query = "select ID, LOGIN_ID, EMAIL_ID, FIRST_NAME, MIDDLE_NAME, LAST_NAME, decode(is_primary, 1, 'true', 'false') IS_PRIMARY, decode(status, 1, 'true', 'false') IS_ACTIVE from user_details where ID = ?";
    List<UserDetails> strLst = return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query, new RowMapper<UserDetails>() {

                    @Override
                    public UserDetails mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                        UserDetails userDetails = new UserDetails ();
                        userDetails .setId(rs.getInt("ID"));
                        userDetails .setIntranetId(rs.getString("LOGIN_ID"));
                        userDetails .setEmailId(rs.getString("EMAIL_ID"));
                        userDetails .setFirstName(rs.getString("FIRST_NAME"));
                        userDetails .setMiddleName(rs.getString("MIDDLE_NAME"));
                        userDetails .setLastName(rs.getString("LAST_NAME"));
   userDetails.setPrimaryAnalyst(Boolean.valueOf(rs.getString("IS_PRIMARY")));
                        userDetails.setStatus(Boolean.valueOf(rs.getString("IS_ACTIVE")));
                        return userDetails;
                }
    }, userId);

    if (strLst.isEmpty()) {
        return " ";
    } else {
        return strLst.get(0);

    }
}
```

This is my code for the query:

```
 @Override
        public UserDetails fetchUserById(int userId) {
            String query = "select ID, LOGIN_ID, EMAIL_ID, FIRST_NAME, MIDDLE_NAME, LAST_NAME, decode(is_primary, 1, 'true', 'false') IS_PRIMARY, decode(status, 1, 'true', 'false') IS_ACTIVE from user_details where ID = ?";
                RowMapper<UserDetails> rowMapper = new RowMapper<UserDetails>(){

                    @Override
                    public UserDetails mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                        UserDetails userDetails = new UserDetails ();
                        userDetails .setId(rs.getInt("ID"));
                        userDetails .setIntranetId(rs.getString("LOGIN_ID"));
                        userDetails .setEmailId(rs.getString("EMAIL_ID"));
                        userDetails .setFirstName(rs.getString("FIRST_NAME"));
                        userDetails .setMiddleName(rs.getString("MIDDLE_NAME"));
                        userDetails .setLastName(rs.getString("LAST_NAME"));
   userDetails.setPrimaryAnalyst(Boolean.valueOf(rs.getString("IS_PRIMARY")));
                        userDetails.setStatus(Boolean.valueOf(rs.getString("IS_ACTIVE")));
                        return userDetails;
                };
                return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query, rowMapper, userId);

        }
```

The error for null user reads
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0

Comment: You've tagged the question as "SQL" but shared code in some other lang. Why do you need to run the query in the first place if you already know it's pointless?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Agreed, this is not a SQL issue. The question needs to be re-tagged to whatever language is being used to execute the query.

Comment: My Java is too rusty to help but the obvious approach is to check userId against null and return an appropriate value without calling MySQL Server. If you actually need to return a `UserDetails` object and you don't have a null-object implementation available, you possibly need to not call the function in the first place.

Comment: I've already answered it. Since he is using a jdbcTemplate to execute the query, he just have to check if an specific exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to use `EmptyResultDataAccessException` and return your empty fields. Something like this:

```
@Override
public UserDetails fetchUserById(int userId) {
    String query = "select ID, LOGIN_ID, EMAIL_ID, FIRST_NAME, MIDDLE_NAME, LAST_NAME, " 
                   + " decode(is_primary, 1, 'true', 'false') IS_PRIMARY, " 
                   + " decode(status, 1, 'true', 'false') IS_ACTIVE "
                   + " from user_details where ID = ?";
    try{
        RowMapper<UserDetails> rowMapper = new RowMapper<UserDetails>(){
            @Override
            public UserDetails mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                UserDetails userDetails = new UserDetails ();
                userDetails .setId(rs.getInt("ID"));
                userDetails .setIntranetId(rs.getString("LOGIN_ID"));
                userDetails .setEmailId(rs.getString("EMAIL_ID"));
                userDetails .setFirstName(rs.getString("FIRST_NAME"));
                userDetails .setMiddleName(rs.getString("MIDDLE_NAME"));
                userDetails .setLastName(rs.getString("LAST_NAME"));
                userDetails.setPrimaryAnalyst(Boolean.valueOf(rs.getString("IS_PRIMARY")));
                userDetails.setStatus(Boolean.valueOf(rs.getString("IS_ACTIVE")));
                return userDetails;
            };
            return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query, rowMapper, userId);
        }
    }catch(EmptyResultDataAccessException e){
        UserDetails userDetails = new UserDetails ();
        //fill the userDetails fields with the empty values
        return userDetails;
    }
}
```